# Batch nested loop doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a mod loader for a game in batch but I can't get it to work with a nested loop.

The command used is this `loadMods.bat mod1.txt mod2.txt ... modN.txt`

This is the code I'm using

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p outputFile="Output File:"

for %%x in (%*) do (
    echo Applying mod from file %%x
    for /f "delims=" %%y in (%%x) do echo %%y >> %fileOutput%
)
echo Finished.
pause
```

The second loop works fine if it's outside the first loop but when I use nested loops I get an `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` error on the second loop.

Comment: You called the variable storing the path of the output file `%outputFile%`, but then you're redirecting output to `%fileOutput%`. This typo is causing the error.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm such a noob xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SomethingDark said, this is caused by a simple typographical issue.

```bat
for /f "delims=" %%y in (%%x) do echo %%y >> %fileOutput%
```

The variable `fileoutput` was undefined, making the `CMD.EXE` sees:

```bat
for /f "delims=" %%y in (%%x) do echo %%y >>
```

and it cannot find an argument after `>>`, causing the error.

---

By the way, when debugging batch files, I'd recommend:

- remove `@echo off`
- run script from `CMD.exe`

These method shows exactly which command(s) go wrong, making debugging easier.

Answer (score 1):

As you appear only to be copying the contents of several files to a single output file you could probably simplify things a little too.

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" Exit/B
Set/P "outputFile= Output File: "
Type %* 2>Nul >"%outputFile%"
Echo( Finished.
Pause
```

*Ensuring the validity of any passed arguments and input string is your responsibility.*

You could even possibly bypass the input parameters:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "outputFile= Output File: "
Type mod*.txt 2>Nul >"%outputFile%"
Echo( Finished.
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!